When can I use a full-function USB-C port as a monitor port?
I have just bought a x86_64 tablet PC that has a beautiful IPS screen, it has a full-function USB-C port, but its 6W CPU is more focused on energy efficiency than performace, which is good in a mobile tablet, but if I was able to use the tablet as a monitor for a performant mini PC when using it pluged in the wall on a desk I could have more CPU power and still keep some mobility of the setup.
As I am not sure if a full-function USB-C can be used as a "video in" port (although I know it can be used as a "video out" port), I have not yet bought the mini PC to test if this works (because if it doesn't that would be somewhat of a waste of money), also I haven't seen or read this being done anywhere. Although, in principle, I belive this should be possible (if not bypassing the entire tablet CPU and OS directly to the tablet screen, at least as a display window within the tablet OS, where the mini PC could be acessed).
To list the hardware that I am considering, to be more technically specific, I have:
A HP Tablet 11-be0014na that has one full-function USB-C port, also it uses a x86_64 CPU and is running Windows 11.
And as the mini PC I was considering a Minisforum EM780 that has, among other ports, two USB4 Ports and one HDMI 2.1 port.
I know that specifically for games there are streaming services that use wifi to connect a mobile device to a more powerfull PC, where the rendering and other calculations are done at the more powerfull stationary PC and the displaying and input reception are done at the mobile device end. Nevertheless the fact that it uses wifi for this probably means there must be quite a lot of lag that could be reduced by a cable connection.
Some people may simply say "then you should have bought a portable monitor instead of a tablet", but the greatest mobile aspect of the tablet was really needed for me, the possibility of "increasing" performance by using a mini PC during non mobile periods, would be something plus.
Any answers or clarifications are welcome.

Check the spec of the tablet itself. If it can be used as monitor, I'm pretty sure the vendor would advertise it. It pretty much has nothing to do whether a port is a "full-function" port. (And such tablet/monitor does exist. I think Linus Tech Tips just showcased one recently.)

Unless it was clearly stated in the manufacturer specifications page for the device it is highly unlikely that the USB C port supports display input. You will either need to use remote desktop software or a video capture device.

Many game streaming tools and services use the graphics hardware of the device to do the video encoding. Latency can be below 30-50ms, which depending on the game could be perfectly acceptable. I wouldn't use it for competitive FPS or games where timing is absolutely key, but it can definitely be usable. How usable depends a lot on your sensitivity to latency and input lag, not everyone can see the delay.

@TomYan the tablet does come with the software Duet display already downloaded, from what I can tell it does exactly what I need, it displays the screen of another PC onto the tablet, (or it only displays the screen of the tablet on another display, or perhaps both, I am not sure), but I don't know if I can use the USB-C as a input source, by connecting a HDMI--USB-C cable with the HDMI end on the mini PC and the USB-C on the tablet, or if this Duet display software only works by wifi.

@FelipeDilho I'm pretty sure software like Duet doesn't require a USB port to have "hardware" video-in support, otherwise it would basically have no competitiveness or reason to exist on the market. (Likely it doesn't even require the source to have a port that has "hardware" video-out support. My guess is it works pretty much like x11vnc.)

What do you mean under "full-function USB-C port"?
